# Angular repeat in tables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have multiple source of income that I want displayed into a table. I will be importing more than 2 values and I want to be able to put them side by side for easy comparing. However, the code below is definitely not working. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/Vkcc9YUnEIc3PuuS8Yv3?p=preview

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat="type in informationNames">{{type}}>
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="type in informationValues1">{{type}}>
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="type in informationNameValues2">{{type}}>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I found this but this doesn't really apply since it is only 1 array and I'll be importing 2+.
[Angular ng-repeat in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515847/angular-ng-repeat-in-table)

Comment: Can you provide a working example? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: it doesn't help us if your not providing code for the controller, `informationNames` could be undefined or a fire breathing unicorn for all we know

Comment: Instead of having three lists of single values you should create one list with three properties: {informationName, informationValue, informationNameValue } and do the repeat on the row.

Comment: Added a Plunker link, https://plnkr.co/edit/Vkcc9YUnEIc3PuuS8Yv3?p=preview.
@mparnisari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could place each repeat into a different row so your code would look like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="type in informationNames">{{type}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="type in informationValues1">{{type}}
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="type in informationNameValues2">{{type}}
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

this way they are all listed veritally

if you want them horizontally and you know all of the list are the same length you can do it like this:

`

```
<table>
     <tr ng-repeat="name in informationNames">
      <td>{{name}}
     </td>
      <td>
       {{informationValues1[$index]}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{informationNameValues2[$index]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I want them side by side. It looks cleaner.

Comment: @SamBush do you mean have the information oriented horizontally? Also does the information have to be in different lists?

Comment: each list will be updates dynamically so they will need to stay seperate. It doesn't really need to be a table either. I was just toying with creating 3 <li> tags even. Honestly as long as they display like Name value value  on every line I don't really care.

Comment: changed my answer to reflect horizontal presentation